# PDE -- Wave Equation with extra term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How would I go about solving the following PDE:

$u_{tt} = u_{xx} + A\sin(\omega t)$

with the boundary conditions: $u(0,t) = 0, u(1,t) = 0, u(x,0) = 0, u_t(x,0) = 0$.

I have tried separation of variables and some work with the Fourier transform to no avail. Any suggestions in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: What's the boundary condition $u_t(x,0)?$  Is it 0?

Comment: To start, represent the forcing term in terms of the eigenfunctions $\sin(n\pi x).$  E.g. $A\sin \omega t = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t) \sin(n \pi x).$  For your problem, $f_n(t)  = \frac{2A}{n\pi} (1 - (-1)^n) \sin \omega t.$

Comment: Then represent $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty G_n(t) \sin (n\pi x).$

Comment: @mattbiesecker Yes it is 0, sorry about that. Thanks for the hint. What do I do with the $G_n(t)$ though?

Comment: You can try substituting for $u(x,t)$ and $A\sin \omega t$ in the PDE, check my math, but I get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [G_n''(t) +  (n\pi)^2 G_n(t) - f_n(t)] \sin (n\pi x) = 0.$     The ODE for $G_n(t)$ can be solved via method of undetermined coefficients. Note that resonance is  possible if $\omega=n\pi,$ but assume that $\omega \neq n\pi$ the first time you solve it.   The arbitrary coefficients in $G_n(t)$ are then determined from the initial conditions.

Comment: That's really clever, thanks for the help! So do I split the cases with resonance and without resonance when combining everything together for the solution to the PDE?

Comment: Yes. $\omega$ is a constant, so treat the resonance case separately.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot you've been a big help. If you'd like you can copy-paste those comments into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, represent the forcing term in terms of the eigenfunctions $\sin(nπx).$ That is, $$A\sin ωt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(t) \sin(nπx),$$ where $$f_n(t)=\frac{2A}{nπ}(1−(−1)^n)\sin ωt.$$ Then represent $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty G_n(t) \sin (n\pi x)$ and substitute into the PDE. This results in 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty [G''_n(t)+(nπ)^2G_n(t)−f_n(t)] \sin(nπx)=0.
$$
The ODE for $G_n(t)$ can be solved via the method of underdetermined coefficients.  The constants $A_n,B_n$ appearing the solution of $G_n(t)$ are determined using the initial conditions.

Note: In the cases where the constant $\omega=n \pi,$ you will have resonance